# Ubuntu terminal running infinitely

Tags: command-line

My Ubuntu terminal started running infinitely while I was trying to install Oracle 10g on my system.

I have tried several commands like <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>,etc and also tried reseting my terminal settings but nothing is working.
Please help!

[image: Here is the screenshot]

Comment: Does that show up each time you open a terminal? If so, the problem may be in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` file (in your home directory).

Comment: yes, it shows up each time

Answer (score 0):

open another terminal and kill the first one?

```
ps ax | grep bash # use the shell you are using
kill -9 that process
```

Comment: there's also `pgrep` for that... What about the root cause of the problem though... hmm